# Use jQuery Sparkline for composite chart with ui-jq in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sparklines

I use jQuery Sparkline for some chart like this:

```
<span ui-jq="sparkline" ui-options="[5,6,7,9,9,5,3,2,2,4,6,7], {type: 'line'}" ></span>
```

but I don't know how to render Composite Sparkline chart because in documentation of Sparkline use this script:

```
 $('#compositeline').sparkline('html', { fillColor: false });
 $('#compositeline').sparkline([4,1,5,7,9,9,8,7,6,6,4,7,8,4,3,2,2,5,6,7], { composite: true, fillColor: false, lineColor: 'red' });
```

how to implement above model of script with `ui-jq`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span id="mySparkline" ...>
```

Use the right selector

```
$("#mySparkline"). ...
```